# Using locks on objects in a Dictionary gives KeyNotFoundException

Tags: c#, multithreading, dictionary, locking, task-parallel-library

I have some code which processes a number of `response` objects from my database in parallel (using `AsParallel()`). Each `response` has many `components`. The `responses` may share the same components. I do some modifications to the `component` data and save it to the db, so I need to prevent multiple threads working on the same `component` object at the same time.

I use locks to achieve this. I have a `ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>` to hold all the necessary lock objects. Like this:

```
private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, object> compLocks = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, object>(); 
var compIds = db.components.Select(c => c.component_id).ToList();
foreach (var compId in compIds)
{
    compLocks[compId] = new object();
}
```

Then later on I do this:

```
responses.AsParallel().ForAll(r =>
{

    ... do some time consuming stuff with web services ...

    // this is a *just in case* addition, 
    // in case a new component was added to 
    // the db since the dictionary was constructed
    // NOTE: it did not have any effect, and I'm no longer 
    // using it as @Henk pointed out it is not thread-safe.
    //if (compLocks[c.component_id] == null)
    //{
    //    compLocks[c.component_id] = new object();
    //}

    componentList.AsParallel().ForAll(c =>
    {
        lock (compLocks[c.component_id])
        {
            ... do some processing, save the db records ...
        }
    });
});
```

This seems to run perfectly fine but towards the end of program execution (it runs for several hours as there are lots of data) I get the following exception:

> Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)

I am sure that the `ConcurrentDictionary` is being populated with every possible `component` ID.

I have 3 questions:

1. **How is this exception even possible, and how do I fix it?**
2. **Do I need a `ConcurrentDictionary` for this?**
3. **Is my understanding of how locking works correct in this instance / is there a better way of doing this?**

### Post-Answer Edit

To make it clear what the cause of all this was, it's that `.AsParallel()` doesn't enumerate the collection of `responses`. It's lazy-evaluated, meaning new `responses` (and therefore new `components`) can be added to the collection during run-time (from other processes). Enforcing a snap-shot with `.ToList()` before the `.AsParallel()` fixed the problem.

My code for adding `component` IDs to `compLocks` during run-time didn't remedy this problem is because it is not thread safe.

Comment: Try debugging the problem with (thrown) exceptions enabled. You might be confused because an AggregateException is only thrown after the parallel loop terminates. If you get the debugger to break at the time of the actual exception, you might get an understanding of what's wrong.

Comment: Another remark: Could it be that db.components changes during execution?

Comment: @PMF - I thought of that and added a line of code which added the missing component id to the ConcurrentDictionary if it didn't exist. I still got the error, which **really** confused me!

Comment: @PMF - the only problem with debugging is that it will slow down the execution time something chronic, which is already about 8 hours :( I can't wait for like a day for the exception to be thrown which is why I thought I'd put it out there for people to offer suggestions first.

Comment: Then post the add-when-missing code. And confirm: can other processes add to the db while this is going on?

Comment: @Henk  - I've added it to the question, and yes they can in theory, however I run it overnight when nobody is working on the system (100% sure of that) so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Why can't you just use transactions with your database? This looks like a horrible missuse of `lock` to me.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191(v=vs.110).aspx) For very large ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> objects, you can increase the maximum array size to 2 gigabytes (GB) on a 64-bit system by setting the <gcAllowVeryLargeObjects> configuration element to true in the run-time environment.

Comment: @NiklasArbin I have ~25000 components - surely that's not too big? It's only storing an `int` and a regular instantiated `object()`

Comment: @theyetiman, you're correct. 25000 integers are far from that in size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) How is this exception even possible?

Apparently it is, but not from the posted code alone. It would happen if data is added to the db (would it be an option to capture `responses` with a `ToList()` beforehand?)

> 2) Do I need a ConcurrentDictionary for this?

Not with a fixed list, but when the solution involves add-when-missing then yes, you need a Concurrent collection.

> 3) Is my understanding of how locking works correct in this instance / is there a better way of doing this?

Not totally sure. The locking looks OK but you will still do the processing of duplicates multiple times. Just not at the same time.

---

Reaction to the edit:

```
if (compLocks[c.component_id] == null)
{
    compLocks[c.component_id] = new object();
}
```

this is not thread-safe. It is now possible that multiple lock objects are created for 1 component_id value.  You need to use one of the `GetOrAdd()` methods.

But I would not expect this to give the exception you're getting, so it's probably not the direct problem.

Comment: Can you explain why a new `response` added to the db would cause a `KeyNotFoundException` on a dictionary of `component` ids? I can understand if it was a new `component` being added, but as explained in my comments above, I tried to mitigate this by doing the 'add-when-missing' (which had no effect anyway).

Comment: I'm going to try your suggestion of performing a `ToList()` on the `responses` first. As well as @Joe's suggestion of changing my lock code.

Comment: Without the 'add-when-missing' part it would explain the specific exception. With that (unsafe) code in place it becomes more complicated.

Comment: "Without the 'add-when-missing' part it would explain the specific exception." - Can you please elaborate on this? I would like to understand why. My unsafe code wasn't originally in there when I got the exception - it was only added to try and fix the error. It didn't work so I removed it.

Comment: When `responses` is lazy-evaluated (no ToList), new records can show up that were not in compIds. Thus giving key-not-found.

Comment: I see. I was under the impression that `.AsParallel()` would enumerate the collection before dispatching the functions to threads. If what you say is true, and a single response were to be added to the database during run-time then new `components` would definitely be created. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: AsParallel() goes through some lengths _not_ to fetch everything at once. `.ToList().AsParallel()` will give you your snapshot.

Comment: Taking a snapshot using `.ToList()` seems to have worked. How incredibly simple - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by replacing:

```
lock (compLocks[c.component_id])   
{
    ...
}
```

by:

```
object compLock;
if (!compLocks.TryGetValue(c.component_id, out compLock)) Debug.Assert(false);
lock(compLock)
{
    ...
}
```

Then set it running and go and get a coffee.  When the assert fails you'll be able to debug and get a better idea of what's happening.

As for your questions:

> 1.How is this exception even possible?

Without seeing the rest of your code, impossible to say.

> 2.Do I need a ConcurrentDictionary for this?

If you initialize the dictionary once from a single thread, then subsequently only ever read from the dictionary, then it doesn't need to be a `ConcurrentDictionary`.

> 3.Is my understanding of how locking works correct in this instance / is there a better way of doing this?

Again, difficuly to say without seeing more code, but I don't see anything obviously wrong with the small sample of code you've posted.  But threading is hard and it's quite possible there are race conditions elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'm going to try the `lock` code change combined with @Henk's suggestion of performaing a `.ToList()` on the `responses` collection. It's running now so I'll let you know whenever it finishes.

Comment: thanks for your input. I've marked @Henk's answer as correct because it was the `.ToList()` that solved it in the end.